# ask about intel xkd capabilities?

Tags: jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I am new To Intelxdk and want to know whether I can achieve the points.

1. Handle limited/no internet connection case
2. Upload file from file manager to the server
3. Sqlite connection, execute queries(select,add,...)
4. Navigate between screens using variables(Ex : user_id)
5. Apply UI design, and handle multiple resolutions for each platform
6. Download file from server to device
7. Use maps for a given longitude and latitude
8. Swipe images by fingers
9. Package the app for Android & iOS
10. Push notification configuration
11. Capture image from camera, save it, and upload it to server
12. Share text to social networks(Facebook,Twitter) using their apis
13. Share text to social networks using intent
14. Call XML webservice, and parse response
15. Call SOAP webservice, and parse response
16. Handle device rotation(landscape)

Sorry for big question,
anyone who has any details about all or one of those points. Please let me know,
I will be grateful.

Comment: 16 questions in one post?

Comment: Thanks Omar For seeing my post , I Only Need Overal View About Intel xdk capabilites

Comment: You're welcome. However, you cant have 16 questions in one post. You'll find answers to most of your question here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also answered this on our forum...

Please see our demo apps and documentation for answers to your questions. I'll try to provide some quick answers below.

Many of your questions presume the XDK is providing platform services -- please note that the XDK provides debug and build services that put your HTML5 code into an embedded webview (an embedded browser window), where many of the features and functions depend on what is available in the embedded webview. This embedded webview container includes JavaScript API "extensions" that provide access to device resources that you normally would be restricted from using in a standard browser, such as access to device features and contacts, but, in general, if you can do something in a browser you can do it in the webview.

Also, keep in mind that the resources available in a webview on a mobile device (memory and CPU) are much more limited than what you are used to on the desktop browser. The desktop browser has nearly unlimited resources, that is not the case with a mobile device. You must design your app to be "lean and mean" for best results. Do not include large numbers of CSS and JS files, especially if you are only using one or two elements within those included apps.

> 1-Handle limited/no internet connection case

An XDK apps does not require a network connection. If your app uses a network connection it is up to you to determine the behavior when there is limited or no network connectivity. If you only try to access the network when the network is available...

> 2-Upload file from file manager to the server

There is no such thing as a "file manager" on a mobile device. How you locate and upload files is very device dependent and how you choose to upload them to a server is also up to you to decide. There are standard HTML5 techniques and a few APIs that can help.

> 3-Sqlite connection, execute queries(select,add,...)

Again, this is device/target platform dependent, it is not dictated by the XDK.

> 4-Navigate between screens using variables(Ex : user_id)

In general, we advise against using multi-page apps, due to JavaScript context changes, inter-page reload times and resource requirements. Single-page apps that use hidden divs to represent multiple pages tend to work better in this environment, especially if you are new to writing such apps.

> 5-Apply UI design, and handle multiple resolutions for each platform

Again, this is completely under your control, how well you can master things like media queries and such. The App Designer tool can help you tremendously in this regard, but it is NOT required. If you have your own layout tools you can use them and utilize the HTML/CSS they generate in your project. Or, you can write your layout by hand. For example, if you like to use Zurb Foundation as a responsive web design tool you can use it here.

> 6-Download file from server to device

Again, what you can do with that file when you get to the device is platform dependent.

> 7-Use maps for a given longitude and latitude

Not XDK dependent, use whatever network mapping service you prefer. You can get Lat and Long numbers by using the geo APIs that are extensions to the normal webview.

> 8-Swipe images by fingers

XDK does not dictate how you handle touch events, this is up to you to design how such events and actions are handled.

> 9-Package the app for Android & iOS

We provide packaging services for Android, iOS and several other mobile targets.

> 10-Push notification configuration

There is a push notification service built-in from AppMobi. However, we are moving to a 100% compatible Cordova contain that will allow you to (in the near future) include any push notification service that has the appropriate Cordova plugin.

> 11-Capture image from camera, save it, and upload it to server

There are APIs present for such actions.

> 12-Share text to social networks(Facebook,Twitter) using their apis

These can all be done using standard HTML5 programming techniques and do not require special services from the XDK.

> 13-Share text to social networks using intent

Intents depend on the specific platform.

> 14-Call XML webservice, and parse response

Use your favorite JS library to parse XML data, the XDK does not restrict this.

> 15-Call SOAP webservice, and parse response

Again, if you have a favorite JS library to parse SOAP data, the XDK does not restrict your use of such a library.

> 16-Handle device rotation(landscape)

Events are present in the standard webviews (precise behavior varies by platform) to help you deal with rotation.